# Stretching + array with object offset = bug?

Tags: modifiers, empty

I created a torus, stretched it (X=1.3), and added an Array modifier (n=5) with an Object Offset (an Empty that does nothing).

The effect is that the stretch is applied to the original copy. it's undone in the second copy and later copies are subsequently narrower. Needless to say this is not what I intend to do. To "fix" this I need to set the stretch values of the Empty to those of the torus.

Why is that necessary? doesn't make sense to me and smells like a bug, as I'd expect that adding a "no-op" Empty to an Array should not affect the result.

[image]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: Apply the scale (Ctrl-A) to the torus.

Comment: @JohnEason Well that obviously fixes the immediate problem, but that doesn't tell me why adding an Empty which does nothing results in scaling things *down*.

Comment: @moonboots attached

Comment: The empty does not do nothing, whether the difference in transform comes from the arrayed object or the empty, there is still a relative difference between the two. If you want the empty to do nothing, set its X scale to 1.3

Answer (score 1):

This is how Array Modifier is supposed to work. There is no bug or error. This is intended functionality and it should be like this. An array in object offset mode takes the transforms of the offset object and repeats them. Those are translation, rotation and scale. If the translation/location, rotation or scale values are different in the object repeated and the offset object, the difference is repeated in the array.

You have to apply the scale of your object with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, or match the offset object's scale so there is no difference in them if you do not want to repeat that difference across your array. That's the whole point of object offset mode in array modifier - you can change not only location, but rotation and scale in arrays with it.